# Assign value in data.table via .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to set a subset of my data to a value.

In the example below I would like to set "carb" to 4 for the subset.

How can I do that directly - in other words, how can I combine the query for the subset with a carb := 4 assignment? The resulting dataset should be the full mtcars, but the subset has carb set to 4.

```
library(data.table)
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)

mtcars[, .SD[1], by = cyl]  
# the subset:
      cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
 2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
 3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2

# required for the subset :
     cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    4
3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: @Henk I guess  you would be getting error by trying `setDT(mtcars)#Error in setDT(mtcars)`.  Perhaps it may work in the earlier versions?

Comment: The subset condition in my case is the .SD[1] since I need to get the first row of each set [a by with multiple terms].

Comment: @akrun - no error, I am using data.table 1.9.3.

Comment: @akrun, try it after doing `data(mtcars)`.

Comment: if/when https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571 gets implemented, you'd be able to do `mtcars[, carb[1] := 4, by = cyl]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this works:

```
 data(mtcars)
 setDT(mtcars)[mtcars[,.I[1], by=cyl]$V1, carb:=4] #based on @Roland's comments

 mtcars[,.SD[1], by=cyl]
  #  cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 #1:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    4
 #2:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
 #3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    4

dim(mtcars)
#[1] 32 11
```

Splitting the above code

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
DT[, .I[1], by=cyl] #V1 gives the numeric index of the rows for the first occurence of each levels of `cyl`
#    cyl V1
#1:   6  1
#2:   4  3
#3:   8  5

 DT[, .I[1], by=cyl]$V1 
 #[1] 1 3 5

 DT[DT[, .I[1], by=cyl]$V1, carb:=4] #assign carb to 4 for those rows
 DT[,.SD[1], by=cyl]
 #   cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 #1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
 #2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    4
 #3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: I see. An alternative could be: DT = data.table(mtcars, key = 'cyl')
DT[, idx := .I]
s = DT[, .SD[1], by = cyl]
DT[s, carb := 4]
DT[, idx := NULL]. But for data.table it feels uncharacteristically verbose.

Comment: @Henk Could you update this on your post.  In the comment, it looks a little difficult to read.  Actually, my code could be joined to a single line, but I thought it would be easier to read by splitting it up.

Comment: Why don't you use `.I[1]` to get the index?

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Normally I already have the data.table, so I am trying to untangle the setDT part. For my education, how would that work [and what is the $V1 ?].

Comment: @Henk `setDT` is converting `data.frame` to `data.table`. `$V1` is the name of the column that is generated (we didn't specify the name for that column, so it automatically assign to `V1`) by `I[1]` which is a numeric index.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> mtcars[, .SD[1], by = cyl][,carb:=4,][]
   cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    4
3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    4
```

or:

```
> mtcars[order(cyl)][!duplicated(cyl)]$carb = 4
> mtcars[order(cyl)][!duplicated(cyl)]$carb
[1] 4 4 4
> mtcars[order(cyl)][!duplicated(cyl)]
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
3: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    4

> head(mtcars)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    4
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    4
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: this selects the carb == 4 condition, but does not set the "4" for the subset - I'll clarify/edit the question.

Comment: thanks - you are right, this indeed sets carb to 4, but now the mtcars dataset is reduced to 3 records. I'll clarify/edit my question.

Comment: Thanks - this leads to the right outcome for this example, but not via the .SD[1] way, which is required for my [real life] problem.